# How to append/join/concat/... a Python Pandas DataFrame in a lambda expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to "add" Series items (whatever is suitable append/concat/join/merge) to a Pandas `DataFrame` like the following which leads to nothing as `pd.concat` does not support `inplace=True`:

```
def aggregate_function(group_item) -> pandas.Series:
    ... process group_item ...
    return processed_series

aggregate_frame = DataFrame()

other_frame.groupby('col_name').apply(lambda group_item: pd.concat([aggregate_frame, aggregate_function(group_item)]))
```

I tried a `for`loop already, where I can do

```
for group_item in other_frame.groupby('col_name'):
    aggregate_frame = pd.concat([aggregate_frame, aggregate_function(group_item)])
```

As I am working with large data sets I would like to avoid the inferior
performance of `for`.

Comment: Why not simply use: `other_frame.groupby('col_name').apply(aggregate_function)`?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Indeed, that worked. I needed to move the `pd.concat`into the aggregate function. thx